# Knowing when to end the loop in a bubble sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
public class sortem {

/**
 * @param args
 */
private static void sort(int s[], int len){
    boolean swap = true;
    int upperBound = 0;
    while(swap){
        swap = false;
        for(int i=0;i<len-(upperBound+1);i++)
            if(s[i]> s[i+1]){
                int t=s[i];
                s[i]=s[i+1];
                s[i+1] = t;
                swap = true;

            }
        upperBound++;
    }
}
private static void print(int s[], int len){
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        System.out.println(s[i]);

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int  size = 10;
    int s[] = new int [size];

    s[0] = 23; s[1] = 34; s[2] = 56; s[3] = 17; s[4] = 61;
    s[5] = 3;  s[6] = 92; s[7] = 44; s[8] = 19; s[9] = 63;
    sort(s, size);
    print(s, size);
}

}
```

Here is my question:

The upperBound variable is outside the for loop and inside the while loop but why do I need this variable. I'm not sure i understand its "control" to the for loop. When i originally wrote this on my own I didn't have this upperBound variable and my loop would end when the i became larger than the length of the array,
like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i > len; i++)
```

it didn't work...Could someone help me understand how this upperBound variable is helping to control the loop boundaries?
I see that the +1 next to it is necessary for the first run, but would it be the same as initializing upperBound to 1 instead of 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that the first time you execute the for loop, the largest element ends up at the end of the array. The second time, the second-largest element ends up at the index right before the end, and so on.

The point behind specifying the `upperBound` variable here is that after you've run the loop `k` times, the last `k` elements in the array are the `k` largest elements, in the correct order. Thus, there's no need to consider them in the loop again (we already know they are in the right spot). Every time we run through the loop, another element ends up in the right spot, and thus, that's one less element we need to consider (hence why the loop condition is `i < len - (upperBound+1)`, the last pair of elements we compare will be the ones *right before* the elements we placed in previous iterations).

Comment: Thanks, excellent explanation. I need to run through the for loop on paper or in my head and I would have figured it out myself, but I didn't think for whatever reason that would help.